# how can I change cpu frequency manually using sysfs & CPUFREQ subsystem?

Tags: linux-kernel

I don't have cpufreq-info/set, utility,
How can I change cpu frequency manually using sysfs & CPUFREQ ?

Answer (score 19):

According to  [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_Dynamic_Frequency_Scaling):

If you are using the userspace governor, you can write to /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed to change the current speed.

```
# echo 700000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed 
# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
cpu MHz  : 697.252 
# echo 900000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed 
# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
cpu MHz  : 976.152
```

To enable userspace governor you must write `userspace` into `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`:

```
# echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```