# Python numba fastmath optimization

Tags: python, numba

I'm learning `numba` right now with the tutorial in the official docs: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/performance-tips.html#performance-tips

Setting `fastmath=True` is supposed to provide a performance increase sometimes as demonstrated in the tutorial but whenever I use `fastmath=True` it's always slower than when I set `fastmath=False`. For example, in the `parallel=True` part of the tutorial, it shows:

| Function Name | Execution time |
| --- | --- |
| `do_sum_parallel` | 9.81 ms |
| `do_sum_parallel_fast` | 5.37 ms |

On my machine it is however:

| Function Name | Execution time |
| --- | --- |
| `do_sum_parallel` | 4.67 ms |
| `do_sum_parallel_fast` | 4.96 ms |

I've observed similar results in other bench-marking in the tutorial, whenever I use `fastmath=True` it's slower. Why is that?

Here are the two functions in the tutorial I used to get the above numbers:

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def do_sum_parallel(A):
    # each thread can accumulate its own partial sum, and then a cross
    # thread reduction is performed to obtain the result to return
    n = len(A)
    acc = 0.
    for i in prange(n):
        acc += np.sqrt(A[i])
    return acc

@njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def do_sum_parallel_fast(A):
    n = len(A)
    acc = 0.
    for i in prange(n):
        acc += np.sqrt(A[i])
    return acc
```

Comment: what code are you actually running?  what flags are you passing to numba?  how are you recording those timings?

Comment: that's what the tutorial says to do, why were those details not provided by OP?  how do you know that's what they were actually doing?

Comment: @SamMason The function names OP used are the same as what was shown in the tutorial. I feel like it was not so much of a jump to assume OP used them.

Comment: @SashSinha presumably they're doing something unusual otherwise they'd be getting the expected performance?  seems better to let the person who knows what they've done fill in the details rather than guessing

Comment: Which version of numba are you using? What is the input data? Is the result the same even if `parallel=False`?

Comment: I *cannot reproduce* the issue on my machine with Numba 0.58.1 using an array of 1048576 64-bit floats : `do_sum_parallel_fast` is twice faster. Please provide the info requested by ken and please share your *exact* benchmark as it might not be correct. Details matters.

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry a little delay here. So I was going through tutorial. My Numba is 0.58.0

Comment: SamMason, @ken
 Sorry a little delay here. So I was going through tutorial. My Numba is 0.58.0

SashSinha edited really well here. So my input is exactly the same as tutorial, but every functions whenever i use fastmath it's actually slower.

ken, as input data, tutorial in the beginning is using np.arange(1.e7). parallel will dramatically improve performance but not fastmath. Basically I can't seems to reproduce similar table

Comment: @JérômeRichard. See my comment above

Comment: @SamMason see my comment above

Comment: But how are you actually doing the benchmarks?  What are you actually timing and how are you timing it?  Please add code showing what you're doing as there's lots you could be doing that would get in the way of numba optimisations

Comment: I tried with `np.arange(1.e7)` on Linux using Numba 0.58.1 and I still get a faster `do_sum_parallel_fast` version : 2.71 ms versus 2.45 ms (+/1 0.1 ms). I think the problem comes from your benchmark which is not provided. This is a critical information. Note that it is not done in the tutorial either (which is clearly not great). Please share the benchmark.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/aGUPfgaW) is a script to easily reproduce my results on any (Debian-like) Linux. I put my results at the end. Please run it and share the results if you run this on Linux (on Windows it should work too with WSL).

Comment: If the result is the same without the parallel feature, let's stick with the function without it, i.e. `do_sum` and `do_sum_fast` in the same tutorial.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I made a comment below your script. I did the script and my time is significant slower than yours, also mathfast seens to increase performance.

Comment: @JérômeRichard my OS is ubuntu 20.0 and CPU 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz

Comment: Check if Intel SVML is installed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76583728/4045774 (The last point). If not this may explain your timings (Different, less precise implementations if fastmath is enabled)

Comment: @max9111 intel-cmplr-lib-rt is installed on my linux disto. Anyway, It might just be processor issue. I'll trust Numba. Another stupid question: can I install intel-cmplr-lib-rt on my Mac with M2 processor? when I pip it failed. "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement". I saw it made distro for amd64, win32, x86. So Im wondering whether it can work on M2

Comment: @max9111 `np.sqrt` should be translated in a `SQRTPS` instruction (SSE), and even actually `VSQRTPS` (AVX) on its processor (like on all modern x86-64 CPU). I think the SVML cannot make that faster, beside using `VRSQRT`+`VDIVPS` which is too inaccurate. It can use some newton raphson iteration but in general, it tends not to be much faster (not to mention it has a higher latency and make the code bigger).

Comment: The main issue is that your *timings are very instable*! Their oscillate between 12 ms to 6 ms! You should not draw any conclusion from. Statistically speaking, the standard deviation is so big that the variation is likely due to statistical fluctuations rather than one implementation being faster than another. You should find why the execution time is so instable in the first place.

Comment: One reason is that you have a *mobile CPU* with a thigh power budget (15 W) so running a multithreaded code using expensive SIMD FP instructions can quickly cause the CPU to throttle. The turbo might also be activated during short period of time but not on all threads because of the power budget. Another reason is that some programs are running on the machine and cause the benchmark to be biased (e.g. the GC of browsers, a background update, etc.).

Comment: You should try to run the code with a manually-set fixed frequency and disable the turbo boost for the test. You can easily disable the turbo boost with [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu) and do the same for the frequency with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271272/how-can-i-change-cpu-frequency-manually-using-sysfs-cpufreq-subsystem). If you want to be safe, you can set the frequency to the base frequency which is `1800000` on your CPU. You should also check the frequency is stable with `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz`.

Comment: The memory configuration can also cause such an issue. This is typically the case if you have multiple DRAM DIMM with different size like 4+2 GiB. Such an issue can be seen with `sudo dmidecode -t memory`. Please share the result of this command.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I tried on my Apple mini running M2 processor. It worked, not a lot of difference between fastmath and regular but at least on par. 
can I install intel-cmplr-lib-rt on my apple m2? Since it's not amd or x86. 
Also I'm very impressed with ur knowledge about Numba and optimisation, are you related to Numba by any chance?

Comment: I missed you use a M2 processor. Classic M2 processor are big-little processor. Numba (like most runtimes) uses a fork-join strategy to run threads in parallel. Big and little core do not run at the same speed. So if you have like 4 big core and 4 little core, Numba certainly runs 8 threads. The OS certainly schedule them on all cores and the performance outcomes is quite impracticable (very dependent of the scheduling). AFAIK, the M2 pro is not much affected by this because the OS should schedule the Numba threads only on big cores.

Comment: Still the number of thread spawned is very likely not efficient. I do not have an Apple system so I do not know exactly how the OS and the M2 exactly behave in practice, bit in general, big little CPU tends to be a nightmare for developers writing parallel applications because of such an effect. I do not think the SVML or similar x86-64 based libraries can be used on the M1/M2 CPU (because they are ARM CPUs and Intel certainly do not support them, IDK if it works with rosetta).

Comment: There is another significant difference with M1/M2 CPUs : the number of SIMD units is AFAIK higher than on x86-64 CPUs : 4 units VS 2 units on x86-64 CPUs. This means scalar codes runs fast compared to the ones using SIMD instructions on the M1/M2 as opposed to x86-64 CPUs. This is certainly why `fastmath=True`, which tends to cause the code to use SIMD instructions rather than scalar ones, does not make things much faster. The timing of the instructions is also certainly different (unfortunately Apple does not document this as opposed to x86-64 CPU vendors).

Comment: *"are you related to Numba by any chance"* I am not a core Numba developer though I tried to contribute a bit to the project (Numpy too). I am a high-performance computing developer often working on native languages, low-level stuff and optimizations. This is why I know such things and interested in Numba ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard wow good to know. I admire that. I'm a scientific computing/computational scientist in training so i really need to get better at HPC as well haha. Thank you so much